# making text scanner but shows black screen instead of camera

Tags: android, camera, ocr, surfaceview

I am trying to make a text scanner application with camera that recognizes text and shows in screen.But instead of showing camera it shows a black screen. How can I solve this.
My code is here

```
  package com.myapp.game.easynepalirecharge;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SurfaceView cameraView;
    TextView textView;
    CameraSource cameraSource;
    final int REQUESTCAMERAPERMISSION = 105;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull final int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case REQUESTCAMERAPERMISSION:


                              if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                                  if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplication(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                      return;
                                  }

                                  try {



                                      cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());


                                  } catch (IOException e) {
                                      e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
                              }

                          }
                      }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

        if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
            Log.v("haha", "error not operational");
        } else {

            cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer).
                    setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                    .setRequestedPreviewSize(3840, 2160)
                    .setRequestedFps(2.0f)
                    .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                    .build();

            cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                                 try {
                                     if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                         // TODO: Consider calling


                                         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUESTCAMERAPERMISSION);
                                         cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());

                                         return;
                                     }


                                 } catch (Exception e) {
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                 }
                             }


                @Override
                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {


                    cameraSource.stop();


                }
            });

            textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void release() {


                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {


                                                final SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();
                                                if (items.size() != 0) {
                                                    textView.post(new Runnable() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void run() {

                                                            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                                                            for (int i = 0; i <= items.size(); i++) {
                                                                TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
                                                                stringBuilder.append(item.getValue());
                                                                stringBuilder.append("\n");


                                                            }

                                                            textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());


                                                        }
                                                    });


                                                }


                                            }


                                        }


            );


        }

    }
    }
```

and another thing I wanna ask. Which one is better. This or the tess two library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you stopped camera properly. Try to do camera functions in thread so that your single task does not be expensive. The reason i thought problem is that get your permission at run time.
try this

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: oh yeah the permission was need for above 23 API level. Thanks saved my day!